# Coefficients of (1+x)(1+2x)...(1+nx)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Are there any formulas for coefficients of the polynomial $(1+x)(1+2x)\ldots (1+nx)$?

I can see that coefficient in front of $x^i$ should be a sum of all products of $i$-tuples of numbers $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$. But still - are there any "concise" formulas (not recursive) to compute them?

Reference would be fine, if exists.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)?

Comment: you may find references searching OEIS

Comment: @KBDave Apparently I haven't remembered it from undergrad classes on discrete maths. Thank you!